# How do I get the first and last 10 records in a table?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, mariadb, query-optimization

I need to find 10 employees with the largest difference between current salary and salary, when they were hired and 10 with the smallest difference.
The table looks like this [salary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM8d2.png) and contains 2844047 records.
My code is:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT emp_no, FIRST_VALUE(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_no ORDER BY from_date) AS `first`
    FROM salaries),
     t2 AS (
         SELECT emp_no, salary AS last
         FROM salaries
         WHERE to_date = '9999-01-01')
(SELECT DISTINCT emp_no, last - first AS `diff`
    FROM t1
             INNER JOIN t2 USING (emp_no)
    ORDER BY `diff`
    LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT DISTINCT emp_no, last - first AS `diff`
    FROM t1
             INNER JOIN t2 USING (emp_no)
    ORDER BY `diff` DESC
    LIMIT 10);
```

but it takes a lot of time to execute this.

Condition where to_date = '9999-01-01' means that employee is still working.

How can I optimize this query, so it will execute faster?

Comment: This sounds like a job for lateral joins, but that's one of those things mysql/maria _still_ doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` is not necessary.  Perhaps this will be a bit faster:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary - first ASC) as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary - first DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM (SELECT s.*,
                  FIRST_VALUE(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_no ORDER BY from_date) AS first
            FROM salaries s
           ) s
      WHERE to_date = '9999-01-01'
     ) s
WHERE seqnum_asc <= 10 or seqnum_desc <= 10;
```